# Contar o total de casas decimais, em Delphi

Tags: delphi, matemática

Preciso contar a quantidade de casas decimais em Delphi (10.1) em uma string, irei usar Edit, validando valores monetários ao digitar, antes de inserir no edit.

Consigo validar se é um Currency válido, mas ao comparar ele entende 1,23 igual 1,230. Claro, é válido.

Sei que existe a opção de arredondar, mas não é meu objetivo nesta etapa, e sim, meramente, contar a quantidade de casas decimais numa string, para, combinando com outras *functions*, impedir a digitação de mais casas, ou caracteres que não façam parte de um currency válido, incluindo mais zeros após 1,23.

Pesquisei bastante, e no momento cheguei a formula abaixo mas não creio ser a melhor (pog) ideia.

```
function ContarDecimaisTESTE(S: string):string;
//necessita verificar se é um (float,currency) valido antes.
var
  Saida: boolean;
  i,j, k: word;
  w: string;
  n: Integer;
begin
  k:= 0;
  Saida:= false;
  n:= length(s);
  i:= n;
  j:= 0;

  for I := 1 to n do
      begin
        w:=Copy(S,i,1);
        j:=j+1;
        if (w = ',') then
          begin
            Saida:=True;
            Break;
          end;
      end;

  if (Saida=True) then
    begin
      k:=(n-j);
    end else
      begin
        k:=0;
      end;
  Result:=IntToStr(k);

end;
```

Cheguei em algo melhor, bem parecido com a ideia do Junior, mas usei mais códigos:

```
function TamanhoCasasDec(S:string):Int64;//Teste
var
  a,b:integer;
  c:string;
begin
  a:=length(S);
  b:=pos(',',S);

  try
    c:=Copy(FilterChars(S,[',']),1,1);//copiar a primeira virgula, se houver
  except
    //
  end;

  if (c = ',') then
    begin
      Result:=Length(Trim(copy(S, b + 1, a - b)));
    end else
      begin
        Result:=0;
      end;

end;
```

Answer (score -1):

No caso não seria apenas contar do separador ate o final da string?

Algo como:

```
function Obter_QtdCasasDecimais(aValor: String): Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(Copy(aValor, Pos(',', aValor)+1, Length(aValor)));
end;
```

Se for isto é simples

Comment: Nao podia ser só Length(aValor)-Pos(',', aValor) ? Nao percebo o uso do Copy :)

Comment: Pode sim, o lance de mostrar uma solução de modo vamos dizer procedural é que o cara acompanhe a evolução do que esta sendo feito. Ali eu ate abreviei alguns rsrsrsrs, eu costumo passar para variável etc...

Comment: Obrigado Júnior Moreira, cheguei em algo bem parecido com o que você postou. eu também quando a cabeça está o limite uso bastantes variáveis sugestivas (vrAntes,vrDepois), coloco até showmessage no meio para ir acompanhando. Depois, simplifico. A que você fez para 12,345 retorna 3, mas para "12" retorna 2. Tirando o tanto de firulas no meu código, consegui retornar 0 para "12" ou "12," , 1 para "12,1" e etc. Creio que vai funcionar.